# Meaning of kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

If something is the 'kernel' of a transformation, say $K(x,x')$, does it mean I should take the integral $$\int K(x,x') f(x')dx'$$

There are many different meanings of kernel and I did not see their application as clear as this.

Comment: Yes, $K$ in the above is called the kernel.